# Huge program size C++ with std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc

I want to compile a small C++ program with `std::regex` (standard regular expressions library).
Compiler: gcc/g++ 4.9.2 on Fedora 21.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main () {
cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"sub-$2");
}
```

It's not possible to compile program with `std::regex` without `-std=c++11`, so the suitable instruction for compiling in terminal is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 code.cpp -o prog
```

My main question is: the source code is very small, but why is the final file size of the compiled program so huge: 480 kilobytes?

Is it because of the influence of `-std=c++11`?

What happened and how can I reduce the size of the final binary program?

UPD1.

Using -Os flag is actually good way to reduce program size with std::regex to 100-120 KB from 480 KB.
But it's strange, that even optimized file with std::regexp more than standart 7-12 kylobytes for C/C++ programs with few strings source code.
For example, it's possible to turn the same regex replace trick with RE2 regexp library (in Fedora 21 "yum install re2-devel") in 8.5 KB binary file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "re2/re2.h"
using namespace std;
int main () {
cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
RE2::GlobalReplace(&s, "\\b(sub)([^ ]*)", "sub-\\2");
cout << s;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -lre2 code.cpp -o prog
```

UPD2.

objdump for std::regex program:

```
0   .interp 00000013    08048154    08048154    00000154    2**0
1   .note.ABI-tag   00000020    08048168    08048168    00000168    2**2
2   .note.gnu.build-id  00000024    08048188    08048188    00000188    2**2
3   .gnu.hash   000000b0    080481ac    080481ac    000001ac    2**2
4   .dynsym 000006c0    0804825c    0804825c    0000025c    2**2
5   .dynstr 00000b36    0804891c    0804891c    0000091c    2**0
6   .gnu.version    000000d8    08049452    08049452    00001452    2**1
7   .gnu.version_r  000000d0    0804952c    0804952c    0000152c    2**2
8   .rel.dyn    00000038    080495fc    080495fc    000015fc    2**2
9   .rel.plt    000002b8    08049634    08049634    00001634    2**2
10  .init   00000023    080498ec    080498ec    000018ec    2**2
11  .plt    00000580    08049910    08049910    00001910    2**4
12  .text   0001f862    08049e90    08049e90    00001e90    2**4
13  .fini   00000014    080696f4    080696f4    000216f4    2**2
14  .rodata 00000dc8    08069740    08069740    00021740    2**6
15  .eh_frame_hdr   00003ab4    0806a508    0806a508    00022508    2**2
16  .eh_frame   0000f914    0806dfbc    0806dfbc    00025fbc    2**2
17  .gcc_except_table   00000e00    0807d8d0    0807d8d0    000358d0    2**2
18  .init_array 00000008    0807feec    0807feec    00036eec    2**2
19  .fini_array 00000004    0807fef4    0807fef4    00036ef4    2**2
20  .jcr    00000004    0807fef8    0807fef8    00036ef8    2**2
21  .dynamic    00000100    0807fefc    0807fefc    00036efc    2**2
22  .got    00000004    0807fffc    0807fffc    00036ffc    2**2
23  .got.plt    00000168    08080000    08080000    00037000    2**2
24  .data   00000240    08080180    08080180    00037180    2**6
25  .bss    000001b4    080803c0    080803c0    000373c0    2**6
26  .comment    0000002c    00000000    00000000    000373c0    2**0
```

objdump for RE2 program:

```
0   .interp 00000013    08048154    08048154    00000154    2**0
1   .note.ABI-tag   00000020    08048168    08048168    00000168    2**2
2   .note.gnu.build-id  00000024    08048188    08048188    00000188    2**2
3   .gnu.hash   00000034    080481ac    080481ac    000001ac    2**2
4   .dynsym 00000180    080481e0    080481e0    000001e0    2**2
5   .dynstr 00000298    08048360    08048360    00000360    2**0
6   .gnu.version    00000030    080485f8    080485f8    000005f8    2**1
7   .gnu.version_r  000000a0    08048628    08048628    00000628    2**2
8   .rel.dyn    00000010    080486c8    080486c8    000006c8    2**2
9   .rel.plt    00000090    080486d8    080486d8    000006d8    2**2
10  .init   00000023    08048768    08048768    00000768    2**2
11  .plt    00000130    08048790    08048790    00000790    2**4
12  .text   00000332    080488c0    080488c0    000008c0    2**4
13  .fini   00000014    08048bf4    08048bf4    00000bf4    2**2
14  .rodata 00000068    08048c08    08048c08    00000c08    2**2
15  .eh_frame_hdr   00000044    08048c70    08048c70    00000c70    2**2
16  .eh_frame   0000015c    08048cb4    08048cb4    00000cb4    2**2
17  .gcc_except_table   00000028    08048e10    08048e10    00000e10    2**0
18  .init_array 00000008    08049ee4    08049ee4    00000ee4    2**2
19  .fini_array 00000004    08049eec    08049eec    00000eec    2**2
20  .jcr    00000004    08049ef0    08049ef0    00000ef0    2**2
21  .dynamic    00000108    08049ef4    08049ef4    00000ef4    2**2
22  .got    00000004    08049ffc    08049ffc    00000ffc    2**2
23  .got.plt    00000054    0804a000    0804a000    00001000    2**2
24  .data   00000004    0804a054    0804a054    00001054    2**0
25  .bss    00000090    0804a080    0804a080    00001058    2**6
26  .comment    0000002c    00000000    00000000    00001058    2**0
```

Main difference is in 12.text: in first case used size - 0001f862 (129122); second - only 00000332 (818).

Comment: Why do you think that this is huge? What did you expect and why?

Comment: Run `strip  ./prog` and check if the file size has changed.

Comment: @Walter, I tried to make clear the problem in UPD1. I expect that program with three lines of code will compiled in small binary, but std::regex with -std=c++11 return disproportionately huge binary result. So I what know: is it normal for std::regex or it's my lack of understanding of C++11 or std::regex.

Comment: @skwllsp, it helps to reduce program to 227 KB: more than RE2 8.5 KB result.

Comment: Are you linking statically or dynamically? Since `<regex>` is heavily templated, I wouldn't be surprised if a much larger fraction of the library code ends up in the binary.

Comment: You can run `objdump -h ./prog` for your std::regex program  and RE2-program and add the output to your question. `objdump` will show some info about the executable.

Comment: @T.C.- actually, speaking from what I know of boost::regex, I'd expect it to not be too much template "magic", hence not too much template code bloat. It's string processing at its core after all. Boost Regex is one of the boost libs that has to be compiled separately, so I guess your question wrt. static/dynamic linking of std::regex here is one core issue.

Comment: Your source code is not 3 lines of code. It is 3 lines *and three headers*. How many lines of code do you think are in those headers? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of RE2, most of the actual implementation is in a shared library, which doesn't become part of your executable file. It is loaded into memory separately when you run the program.

In the case of `std::regex`, this is actually just an alias for `std::basic_regex<char>`, which is a template. The compiler instantiates the template and builds it into your program directly. Although it is possible for templates to be instantiated inside shared libraries, they often aren't, and the `std::basic_regex<char>` is not in the shared library in your case.

As an example. Here is how to create a separate shared library with the regex instantiation:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "regex.hpp"

int main () {
  std::cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
  std::string s {"There is a subsequence in the string\n"};
  std::basic_regex<char> e {"\\b(sub)([^ ]*)"};
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"sub-$2");
}
```

regex.hpp:

```
#include <regex>

extern template class std::basic_regex<char>;

extern template std::string
  std::regex_replace(
    const std::string&,
    const std::regex&,
    const char*,
    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type
  );
```

regex.cpp:

```
#include "regex.hpp"

template class std::basic_regex<char>;

template std::string 
  std::regex_replace(
    const std::string&,
    const std::regex&,
    const char*,
    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type
  );
```

build steps:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -c -fpic regex.cpp
g++ -shared -o libregex.so regex.o
g++ -o main main.o libregex.so -Wl,-rpath,. -L. -lregex
```

On my system, the resulting file sizes are:

```
       main:  13936
libregex.so: 196936
```

Answer (score 4):

First, as it's already said in comments, you should measure the size of optimized binary after doing `strip` or using the `size` utility. Otherwise you pay too much attention to debug info stored in the binary. That info normally doesn't occupy the RAM even if you really run that binary.

Second, the actual answer — most of the binary size comes from regex itself and other things in `std` behind it. You can inspect this using `readelf` utility, like: `readelf -sW prog | c++filt` — shows all the functions in the binary with their sizes. It seems that quite a large portion of regex implementation is left as template functions which instantiated in your binary. GCC authors might instantiate more in `libstdc++` instead, to allow sharing, like they do with some other things, e.g. some methods of `string`.

One more not very famous binary size optimization technique: ICF (identical code folding) implemented in `gold` of binutils. Add `-fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--icf=safe` to your linker flags.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the size by setting optimization:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o prog code.cpp
```

The `-O3` flag means maximum optimization. In my machine that reduces the executable from `519K` to `142K`

You can also use `-Os` to optimize for size. On my machine that further reduces the size to `120k`.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -o prog code.cpp
```

Comment: This does **not answer the question**. Btw, clang 3.5 on Mac OsX gives 103Kb with -Os and 104Kb with -O3.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer! It's actually good way to reduce program size. But it's strange, that even optimized file with std::regex more than 15 kb: after all another regex library (like RE2 or PCRE; UPD1 to the question) don't create big binary from small source code. 
Now it seems, that std::regexp is not good solution for regular expressions in C/C++ (especially if it is considered that std::regex doesn't work normally before gcc/g++ 4.9).

Comment: @СергейИванопуло You're looking at it backwards. Add *another* regexp to your code and see how the code size changes. If your application is so big that you worry about its size, you'll be having many, many regexes, so what you care about really is the incremental cost, not the initial cost. The initial cost will amortize over many uses of the regex. And yes, you **must** strip symbols from the executable.